# Sum the first $n$ terms of the series $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^2 + 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3^2 + 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4^2 + \cdots$

Tags: summation, summation-method

## The question

Sum the first $n$ terms of the series:
$$ 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 2^2 + 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 3^2 + 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4^2 + \cdots. $$

This was asked under the heading using method of difference and the answer given was
$$ S_n = \frac{1}{10}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(2n+3). $$

## My approach

First, I get $$ U_n=n(n+2)(n+1)^2. $$

Then I tried to make $U_n = V_n - V_{n-1}$
in order to get $S_n = V_n - V_0$.
But I really don't know how can I figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the formula as
$$\sum_2^{n+1}k^2(k+1)(k-1)=\sum_2^{n+1}k^4-\sum_2^{n+1}k^2.$$
It is a well known formula that
$$1+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$
Due to [Fermat](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/sums-of-powers-of-positive-integers-pierre-de-fermat-1601-1665-france), we also have
$$1+2^4+3^4+\cdots+n^4=\frac15n^5+\frac12n^4+\frac13n^3-\frac1{30}n.$$
Just substitute in your values to get the result.

Comment: thank you for your link, i really need that. @user496634 Sir

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$\sum_{r=2}^n{r^2(r+1)(r-1)}=\sum_{r=2}^n{r^2(r^2-1)}=\sum_{r=2}^n{r^4}-\sum_{r=2}^n{r^2}$$
Just use (or show) the well-known formulae to evaluate this.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+2)(k+1)^2&=\sum_{k=1}^n (k+3)(k+2)(k+1)k-2\sum_{k=1}^n (k+2)(k+1)k\\
&=24 \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k+3}{4}-12 \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{k+2}{3}\\
&=24\binom{n+4}{5}-12\binom{n+3}{4}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot @Durgesh Tiwari Sir.I really don't know what is **Hockey-stick identity**.Your answer let me to know it :)